# ¿como aumentar el valor de una variable mediante múltiples selecciones en checked listbox MS Visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que estoy haciendo un programa que debe sumar valores según las opciones que se escojan en un checked listbox y ese valor multiplicarlo por el numero de dias que se digitan en un textbox en MS visual basic. el valor de las variables es el siguiente: desayuno As Double = 12000
almuerzo As Double = 20000, comida As Double = 20000 y el alojamiento si se escoje debe de mostrar un inputbox para ingresarle el valor por teclado y asi sumarlo con las otras que se escojan, el problema es que cuando selecciono varias opciones o todas, solo suma a la variable Tviaticostotal el valor del desayuno o del primero que se selecciono [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui les adjunto mi codigo

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub dias_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtdias.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsiguiente.Click


        'En este bloque se crean los condicionales individuales en caso de que el usuario solo escoja una opcion
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) Then
            Tviaticostotal = desayuno
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) Then
            Tviaticostotal = almuerzo
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) Then
            Tviaticostotal = comida
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3) Then
            InputBox("Ingrese el valor del alojamiento", alojamiento)
            Tviaticostotal = alojamiento
            'En este bloque se crea el condicional en caso de que el usuario escoja desayuno y otra de las 3 opciones
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) Then
            Tviaticostotal = desayuno + almuerzo
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) Then
            Tviaticostotal = desayuno + comida
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3) Then
            InputBox("Ingrese el valor del alojamiento", alojamiento)
            Tviaticostotal = desayuno + alojamiento
            'En este bloque se crea el condicional en caso de que el usuario escoja almuerzo y otra de las 3 opciones
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) Then
            Tviaticostotal = almuerzo + desayuno
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) Then
            Tviaticostotal = almuerzo + comida
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3) Then
            InputBox("Ingrese el valor del alojamiento", alojamiento)
            Tviaticostotal = almuerzo + alojamiento
            'En este bloque se crea el condicional en caso de que el usuario escoja comida y otra de las 3 opciones
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) Then
            Tviaticostotal = comida + desayuno
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) Then
            Tviaticostotal = comida + almuerzo
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3) Then
            InputBox("Ingrese el valor del alojamiento", alojamiento)
            Tviaticostotal = comida + alojamiento
            'En este bloque se crea el condicional en caso de que el usuario escoja todas las opciones
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(2) And CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3) Then
            InputBox("Ingrese el valor del alojamiento", alojamiento)
            Tviaticostotal = desayuno + almuerzo + comida + alojamiento
            'Se crea el condicional en caso de que el usuario no escoja nada
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(-1) Then
            MsgBox("Por favor seleccione una opcion", 64)
        End If

        Tviaticostotal = Tviaticostotal * txtdias.Text
        MsgBox(Tviaticostotal)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en una estructura `If .... ElseIf ....` únicamente se evalúa la primera condición que se cumple.

Es decir si el primer elemento está chequeado se ejecuta la primera condición, ninguna más.

Deberías ir comprobando cada check de manera independiente e ir añadiendo el importe según si está marcado o no.

Algo así:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Tviaticostotal = 0
    ' Si se ha seleccionado desayuno
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) Then
        Tviaticostotal += desayuno
    End If
    ' Si se ha seleccionado almuerzo
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(1) Then
        Tviaticostotal += almuerzo
    End If
    ' Si se ha seleccionado comida
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(3) Then
        Tviaticostotal += comida
    End If
    ' Si se ha seleccionado alojamiento
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(0) Then
        InputBox("Ingrese el valor del alojamiento", alojamiento)
        Tviaticostotal += alojamiento
    End If
    ' Si el importe es 0 no se ha seleccionado nada
    If CType(Tviaticostotal, Decimal) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Por favor seleccione una opcion", 64)
    Else 
        Tviaticostotal = Tviaticostotal * CInt(txtdias.Text)
        MsgBox(Tviaticostotal)
    End If
End Sub
```